# The new duplicate UI is messing with my reflexes

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, design

This keeps happening to me. I open a question that has some VTC as duplicate. And I find myself about to upvote the question. When I stop myself, I have come to realize why it happens:

[image]

I am not sure what to suggest, but I do feel a little disoriented when I deal with these questions. Maybe have a link in the dupe banner that I could use to express my agreement (or disagreement, if we ever implement vote-not-to-close-in-parallel right from the question) would let me see the voting buttons as belonging to the question again?

Comment: Shog offhandedly suggested a "agree/disagree" option for the dupe-banner, I like that idea. Ideally it'd allow us to remove the banner if we disagree that it's a dupe too. So that way the close vote stays but the banner doesn't, in those cases where it's kinda or not really a dupe, but it's more NARQ or something else. The buttons could be inside the gray background so they're more clearly associated with the dialog than the vote buttons

Comment: What do you mean by VTC?

Comment: @BrianWebster: Vote to Close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, only the question asker will see the "This question may already have an answer here" banner.

If the question becomes closed, the banner will then be visible for all.