# Make the "Possible duplicate" auto comment note that the dupe has answers

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

The Possible duplicate auto-comment is pretty bare bones right now; just "Possible duplicate of [title of duplicate as link]".

I've noticed since we can now only close questions as duplicates of answered questions, we can make the comment a bit friendlier; it's not just a dupe (sadface), it has my answers (happyface!). [Waxeagle suggested something similar to this, a comment of his own](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/22988/initiative-check-abilities-4th-edition-dd#comment42559_22988). Here's another possible wording:

> This question appears to be a duplicate of [link] which already has [n] answers; see if you can find your answer there or edit your question to clarify why those answers do not suit your situation.

The edit bit is something extra I often throw in when I'm only 90% sure a post is a dupe, to see if I can goad more details out of the asker.

There's also two edge cases that allow dupe close votes without the souce question being answered; should probably still get the old comment form. These cases are MSO questions (any question can be voted as a dupe without answers)  and where the dupe is also posted by the same user. In fact in that second case the auto comment could be something like:

> This question appears to cover the same ground as your earlier question [link]. There's no need to repost, if you need to update your earlier question simply [edit it] (link to edit original Q).

Comment: I'm wax eagle and I endorse this feature request.

Comment: Whoa now, "Possible duplicate"? I think you mean "possible duplicate"; it'll be a cold day in hell before SE starts capitalizing that comment

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Well the new one's a full sentence, so they no longer have a reason to not capitalize it.

Answer (score 5):

The OP actually gets a huge in-your-face box at the very top as soon as a close-as-dupe vote is cast:

[image]

– you just don't see it, since it's only shown to the question owner.

Comment: For why you don't see it, check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167730/the-new-duplicate-ui-is-messing-with-my-reflexes

Comment: I had actually forgotten about that thing. Are they actually pinged by that though?

Comment: Is there a good reason to not make the auto comment nicer and less terse though? Or if this is the case, to have it at all?

Comment: @waxeagle http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166527/stop-generating-possible-duplicate-comments

Comment: @Ben, [the comments will ping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166527/stop-generating-possible-duplicate-comments/167980#167980), not the big box. Those who click a comment from their inbox might not see the box on top, but I feel it's still the OP's responsibility to check on their question quite often.